# trigger email to different ids depend on loglevel

Tags: java, log4j

I created an application with different levels of logging. Now I got into a situation to log errors to dev team and fatal to dev and admin. here is the code I had given a try..

```
    log4j.rootlogger=DEBUG, email, email2
    #email
    log4j.appender.email=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
    log4j.appender.email.SMTPHost=smtp.company.com
    log4J.appender.email.Threshold=error
    log4j.appender.email.From=emailNotification
    log4j.appender.email.To=dev@company.com
    log4j.appender.email.SMTPUsername=user@company.com
    log4j.appender.email.Subject=email Notification from Tomcat Server
    log4j.appender.email.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.email.layout.ConversionPattern=%d%d{dd MMM HH:mm:ss}%p %t %c - %m%n
    log4j.appender.email.BufferSize=1

    #email2
    log4j.appender.email2=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
    log4j.appender.email2.SMTPHost=smtp.company.com
    log4J.appender.email2.Threshold=FATAL
    log4j.appender.email2.From=emailNotification
    log4j.appender.email2.To=admin@company.com, manager@company.com
    log4j.appender.email2.SMTPUsername=user@company.com
    log4j.appender.email2.Subject=email Notification from Tomcat Server
    log4j.appender.email2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.email2.layout.ConversionPattern=%d%d{dd MMM HH:mm:ss}%p %t %c - %m%n
    log4j.appender.email2.BufferSize=1
```

when I run my application with

```
    logger.error("error:"+e);
```

it was triggering email to admin and manager also. so even it is error/fatal it is triggering to all.

any trick? can someone help me.

Comment: See if [this](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2008/07/send-email-alerts-using-log4j-howto.html) helps; it implies the threshold bit is broken.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in "log4J.appender.email2.Threshold" (letter J is in CAPS). ERROR is the default value, so it doesn't matter in the email1.

In case someone is copy-pasting this code snippet...